# Count of employees who changed from position 1 to position 2, position 1 to position 3, position 2 to position 3 in Tableau

Tags: logic, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have an "Employee ID", and "Work position" as a field in Tableau and there are employees who are promoted to a higher level with the same employee ID. I want to get a count of employees who moved from position 1 to position 2 say out of 500 employees 100 employees were promoted to position 2, and also 30 employees were promoted from position 1 to position 3, position 2 to position 3, position 2 to position 4, position 3 to position 4.
I am ok with having individual calculated fields like below,

```
#Emp(1 to 2)
#Emp(1 to 3)
#Emp(2 to 3)
#Emp(2 to 4)
#Emp(3 to 4)
```

5 different fields to get a count of employees whose positions changed.

my existing fields hold values like this:

[image]

Expected output as per the sample data above,

```
Calculated field "#Emp(1 to 2)" holds a value equal to 3 which is Row [3,4],[12,13],[15,16]
Calculated field "#Emp(1 to 3)" holds a value equal to 2 which is Row [6,7],[15,17]
```

I want above-calculated field in Tableau
Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is anyone every demoted? Or promoted twice in a year? or skip a position? This is possible, just realize that this schema allows alot of ambiguity. It would be better to find/create a table that showed each position change -- i.e. columns like Employee ID, Date, Previous Position, New Position

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Given your question, you need only compare the minimum and maximum positions found for each employee. One way is to create an LOD calc as in this image. You could also create sets of promoted employees instead.